# Hardrive won't mount on 12.10

Tags: hard-drive

I just upgraded to 12.10 and one of my media hard drives won't mount. The drive shows up on /dev/sda but doesn't mount. dmesg|tail

```
[  289.496933] FAT-fs (sda1): Unrecognized mount option "x-gvfs-show" or missing value
[  292.502310] FAT-fs (sda1): Unrecognized mount option "x-gvfs-show" or missing value
[  299.540914] FAT-fs (sda1): Unrecognized mount option "x-gvfs-show" or missing value
[  307.700473] FAT-fs (sda1): Unrecognized mount option "x-gvfs-show" or missing value
[  307.804819] FAT-fs (sda1): Unrecognized mount option "x-gvfs-show" or missing value
[  698.017043] FAT-fs (sda1): Unrecognized mount option "x-gvfs-show" or missing value
[  703.933411] FAT-fs (sda1): Unrecognized mount option "x-gvfs-show" or missing value
[  704.055936] FAT-fs (sda1): Unrecognized mount option "x-gvfs-show" or missing value
[  706.293292] FAT-fs (sda1): Unrecognized mount option "x-gvfs-show" or missing value
[ 1134.268187] FAT-fs (sda1): Unrecognized mount option "x-gvfs-show" or missing value
```

Comment: I may have found part of the problem.The file system is FAT (32-bit version). It mounted fine in 12.04 but mount in 12.10 64-bit

Comment: My NTFS formatted drive mounts fine. I guess my question should be changed to: Will a FAT (32-bit version) formatted drive that mounted in 12.04 fail to mount properly in 12.10?

Comment: I think I may have found the problem here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/1011257  but it doesn't explain the work around well enough for me to fix my problem. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this bug still exists in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I post the following solution that I actually found on the [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/1011257) you posted in your last comment :

> try comment=x-gvfs-show instead of comment=gvfs-show (instead of x-gvfs-show)

For people using Disks utility, just uncheck "Show in user interface" in the Mount Options of the partition, and then add *comment=x-gvfs-show* in the list of options below Symbolic Icon Name :

[image]

This should fix the issue.