# HDD initially invisible after startup for applications but not for Ubuntu itself

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, kodi

I am fairly new to Ubuntu, so I hope someone can help to solve this problem or guide me to get in the right direction.

I have installed Ubuntu version 14.04 LTS on a new AMD A4-5000 APU. The OS is running on a Kingston V300 120Gb SSD. The OS is running fine.

I have installed a second HDD drive after I finished the initial Ubuntu installation. This disc is a 750 Gb former (windows) laptop HDD. I have deleted the partition first, re-partitioned it and formatted it with EXT4. 
At first everything seems to work fine. Within Ubuntu you can see and do everything with the disc as expected.

But the strange thing comes after starting a application, for example Kodi. When you browse to the disc, the disc is not recognized. I have all my media located at the disc, so I can not access it. I found out that when I access the disc physically first in Ubuntu before starting Kodi, it recognize the disc and you can use it as normal.

Now my question is, what seems to be the problem and how can I solve this?

Thanks,

Robert

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your disk is not mounted at boot, so you must click it in Ubuntu first to mount it before it will show in any applications.

You will need some information for it to auto-mount, first the name of the disk ie `dev/sda or dev/sdb` and also a location to mount the disk (I will use your home folder for this example,system default is /media)

First back up then open this file

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /home/youruserhere
```

Editing for your users /home, then

```
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

Be careful with this file as it can quite easily cause you system to not boot.

Now we will add the disk to the file so it auto mount, at the bottom of the page add this

```
#device        mountpoint             fstype    options  dump   fsck

/dev/sd?    /home/yourname/mydisk    ext4    defaults    0    1
```

Edit the line device to match your disks name and edit the mount point to your liking, then save and reboot and your disk should be mounted at boot.

Thanks to @msys for his [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154180/how-to-mount-a-new-drive-on-startup), please give him a upvote if this works for you.

Comment: I have tried your instructions, but it ended up in an error. After rebooting, Ubuntu started up and stalled. After  a while I pressed esc and Ubuntu reported the error that it could not connect the drive and asked if you wanted to boot the disc manually or automatically. The auto choice resulted in the same error and the manually choice let Ubuntu to start up 'as normal'.

I have also tried some other ways via the answer-link, but it resulted unfortunately in the same error. I have no idea why this occurs, but I am glad for your help so far.

Comment: Could you show me the exact error message, if it goes away fast at boot, use a phone to photograph it, upload it at http://imgur.com/ and link it here, I will edit it in to the question for you

Comment: I think I have come in the right direction:

See post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/206519/hardrive-wont-mount-on-12-10

I had installed Mint, instead of Ubuntu, to see how this works out. I still had the same problem. But trying to make a screenshot I saw an error in the screen, when looking this up I found this post and it worked! Although the system is working on Mint 17.2 now...